# Call function of included JavaScript code from another included JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function-calls

I'm trying to work with different loaded `JavaScript` in my page, but I'm not able to let them talk.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery144.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="shared_functions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="page_function_callers.js"></script>
</html>


// shared_functions.js
$(document).ready (function () {
    function sayHello (what) {
        alert (what);
    }
});

// page_function_callers.js
$(document).ready (function () {
    $("div.my_button").click (function () {
        sayHello ("Hello world!");
    });
});
```

I work with jQuery and I'd like to use this way because it should let me recyle many public methods. Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare "sayHello" (does anybody remember that Charlotte Church song? Gosh, the memories ...) inside the "ready" function, it's local to that function.  You can make it global if you like by doing this:

```
window['sayHello'] = function sayHello(what) {
  alert(what);
};
```

(It's nice to give the function a "local" name — the name after the "function" keyword — because then the function won't show up as "anonymous" in Firebug.)

I would encourage you to investigate making your global function into a jQuery plugin, or at least a jQuery "global" by putting it on the jQuery object instead of "window".

Answer (score 3):

The function `sayHello` is declared inside the scpoe of the `DOMReady` event ( `$(document).ready` ). It will not be available outside of that scope. But there is no *need* to declare a function inside that scope. Even if `sayHello` uses a lot of DOM objects (which in your example it doesn't), it will not be executed until it's being called, so the only thing you need to make sure is that such a function is not *called* until after DOMReady.

So you can simply remove the first and the last line in shared_functions.js, i.e. `$(document).ready(function() {` and `});` respectively, and your code will work.

Answer (score 2):

Try defining the function `sayHello` outside of your call `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code above, the sayHello() method is only defined inside the anonymous function's scope.

This code might work better for you:

```
// shared_functions.js
window.MyNamespace = window.MyNamespace || {};
MyNamespace.sayHello = function(what)
{
  alert(what);    
};

// page_function_callers.js
$(document).ready (function ()
{
    $("div.my_button").click (function ()
    {
      MyNamespace.sayHello('hello world');    
    });
});
```

Make sure you're loading your JS files in the right order tho. There are more elegant solutions out there, but this is a fairly simple and straightforward one.

One advantage to this approach would be not polluting the global namespace.

Comment: your code will work, but what's the point? why postpone the declaration until DOMReady, and then extract it from that scope, rather than declaring it outside of the DOMReady context to begin with? and are you aware that the namespace is redundant here; simply typing `window.sayHello =...` would've worked equally well...

Comment: Modified the code to reflect your comments. I'd still suggest placing this code under a namespace, if possible.